# Notation for a zeta function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers, zeta-functions

What does this notation mean:

[image]

To provide some context, here are some of the exercises related to it:

[image]

I initially thought the notation was such that [image] $cos(2pi/n^n)+sin(2pi/n^n)$.

This doesn't quite seem like the proper interpretation to me.

I noticed that since $x=cos(t), y=sin(t)$ would graph a circle in the xy-plane,
$x^2+y^2$ will always be equal to $1$, I thought perhaps this was related to the direction we should be heading in for this exercise.

However that line of logic breaks down when I look at the following exercises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the zeta function, and in short, you are overthinking the notation. You can choose any variable you like if you would prefer. I'll use $\alpha$.

So fix an $n$, and let $\alpha = \cos(2\pi/n) + i\sin(2\pi/n)$, which also happens to be $e^{2\pi i/n}$. When we say $\alpha^n$, we mean "raise $\alpha$ to the $n$th power", like we usually mean when we write an exponent. So $\alpha^n = \left( \cos (\frac{2\pi}{n} ) + i\sin (\frac{2\pi}{n} )\right)^n$, which you should show is also equal to $1$.